# File corrupted, how do I reinstall packages on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management

After an unclean shutdown, fsck reported corruption in several parts of the filesystem, apparently affecting installed packages (luckily no user data was affected).

Is there an easy way how I can reinstall these packages from scratch, e.g. tell apt or dpkg to install the same package again, without changing its flags (especially preserving the auto-installed flag)?

I have a list of the affected files and, with some effort, could figure out which packages I would need to reinstall. Alternative is to reinstall everything installed on the system.

Comment: `apt-get --reinstall install packagename`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti in theory yes, turns out it’s not quite as trivial as I thought to figure out the exact package for the files (for which I have the paths). Any ideas?

Comment: @user149408 `dpkg -S /full/path/of/the/corrupted/file` will give you the packaged that installed the file.

Comment: @xhienne thanks, that worked. Currently going through the list.

Comment: This worked. Anyone of those commented care to make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For each of your corrupted file, the package that installed your file can be obtained with:

```
dpkg -S /full/path/of/the/corrupted/file
```

You can then reinstall it with the command:

```
apt-get --reinstall install package
```

If all your corrupted files are in a single file `list.txt`, then you can obtain all the associated packages with:

```
dpkg -S $(cat list.txt) | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u
```

And of course install all those packages with that single command:

```
apt-get --reinstall install $(dpkg -S $(cat list.txt) | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u)
```